# Options of simple product on home page

Tags: product, phtml

I want to show one product on home page. The product should be shows same as on product view, not like list view.

I can get name and sku of product in above code but I don't know how to show custom options of product.

```
<?php

$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product_id = 8;
$_product = $obj->load($product_id);

echo $_product->getName();

?>
```

You can see the image what I want. That I can see the one product on home page.

[image]

Could you help me?

Comment: post some code you're working with.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to use product page as home page is to set System->Configuration->General->Web->default Pages->Default Web URL to "catalog/product/view/id/8", here 8 is product ID.
Note, that you will have to similar pages, so add canonical url to product page.